# How to communicate between Docker container and Linux host over SCTP

Tags: docker, sctp

I tried to listen to SCTP on the docker container and connect to there from the Linux host machine. But it seems the connection timed out.
Is there any way to communicate between host and container over SCTP?

FYI: It looks container-to-container SCTP communication works fine.

Detailed information is the following:

#### Dockerfile for `test-container`

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y ncat
```

#### docker run

```
$ sudo docker run --rm --name sctp-server -p 9999:9999/sctp test-container:latest ncat --sctp -lv 9999
```

#### SCTP request (timeout)

```
$ ncat --sctp 127.0.0.1 9999
Ncat: TIMEOUT.
```

#### docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:02:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:01:20 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

#### FYI: Container-to-Container SCTP communication (works fine)

```
$ sudo docker network create -d bridge sctp
$ sudo docker run --rm --name sctp-server --net=sctp sctp-test:latest ncat --sctp -lv 9999
$ sudo docker run --rm --name sctp-client --net=sctp sctp-test:latest ncat --sctp 172.18.0.2 9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the cause of this problem.
The reason for the timeout is it used the same SCTP port between host and container.

When I launched a container with
different ports like `sudo docker run --rm --name sctp-server -p 19999:9999/sctp test-container:latest ncat --sctp -lv 9999` and run `ncat --sctp 127.0.0.1 19999` on the host machine, it worked fine.

I'm not confident but I suspect the behavior of iptables.

Comment: I put an issue for this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41631